Con jQuery, elemento no se oculta
Mi código en js es bastante simple, pero tengo un detalle: al momento de ocultar un elemento, intento ocultar un contenido padre pero no lo oculta,
pero cuando lo paso al contenido hijo, sí lo oculta, pero me queda el contenedor padre vacío y no se oculta del todo.
Mi código es el siguiente:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        #formContainer {
            background-color: goldenrod;
        } 
        #form {
         background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>

 
    <h1>$('#form').hide()</h1> 
    
  <!-- No oculta el elemento -->
    <div class="formContainer d-flex d-block" id="formContainer" >
           <!-- Si oculta el elemento -->
        <form id="form" action="">
            <input type="text" id="title" class="w-100" >
            <input type="text" id="description" class="w-100">
            <div class="d-flex d-inline">
                <input type="submit" class="w-50"  value="addNote">
                <input type="submit" class="w-50"  value="cancel">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

        //createNote
        $('.createNote').click( ()=>{
        $('#formContainer').show();
    } )

    //form
    $(document).ready( ()=>{
       $('#form').hide()
    } )

</script>
</body>
</html>

estos son los resultados
con el elemento padre no oculta el elemento padre

https://i.imgur.com/LY53PcE.png
estos son los resultados con el elemento hijo si oculta el elemento

https://i.imgur.com/PV7e2vl.png
y en ambos casos en consola no muestra ningun error aparente.

podrian regalarme alguna sugerencia?. Gracias

Es probable que haya algún problema, pero no está en el código que has publicado, pues a mi me ha funcionado bien tanto con el padre como con el hijo. Asegúrate que tu HTML está bien formado, probablemente se está quedando algún tag sin cerrar.

muchas gracias amigo revisare mi codigo.

que sale en la consola de desarrollo del navegador ???

Hola amigo no muestra ningun error pero estoy seguro que es alguna novatada que estoy haciendo pero no me doy cuenta jaja >:,v .

Tu código funciona. No será el chacé del navegador que te está molestando?

gracias por tus consejos, lo probare en otros navegadores pero de momento me quede con mi solucion echiza jaja.

Me desespere de mi error por lo que en un arrebato de locura descidi agregar una capa extra antes del div#formContainer y ponerle la clase .hide y al parecer funciono, aunque obvio no es una respuesta, porque no responde el porque no se oculta el elemento div#formContainer sin usar una capa extra, pero lo publico a modo de sugerencia y no hacer mas larga la pregunta es un misterio muy misterioso.
Asi actualize el codigo
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
        #formContainer {
            background-color: goldenrod;
        } 
        #form {
         background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- No oculta el elemento -->
    <h1>$('.hide').hide()</h1> 
    
    <div class="hide">
        <div class="formContainer d-flex d-block" id="formContainer" >
            <!-- Si oculta el elemento -->
         <form id="form" action="">
             <input type="text" id="title" class="w-100" >
             <input type="text" id="description" class="w-100">
             <div class="d-flex d-inline">
                 <input type="submit" class="w-50"  value="addNote">
                 <input type="submit" class="w-50"  value="cancel">
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

        //createNote
        $('.createNote').click( ()=>{
        $('#formContainer').show();
    } )

    //form
    $(document).ready( ()=>{
       $('.hide').hide()
    } )

</script>
</body>
</html>

Y estos son los resultados de mi desenfreno

tocara pasarlo al codigo principal haber si si jala deseenme suerte.

Si funciono banda :,,,V ...
